# ERROR : self.slide.placeholders[2].insert_picture(data[2]) AttributeError: 'SlidePlaceholder' object has no attribute 'insert_picture'

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to add images to `python-pptx` file using this code but it shows error.

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os

prs = Presentation()

class Myslide:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.layout = prs.slide_layouts[data[3]]
        self.slide=prs.slides.add_slide(self.layout)
        self.title=self.slide.shapes.title
        self.title.text=data[0]
        self.subtitle=self.slide.placeholders[1]
        self.subtitle.text=data[1]
        if data[2] != "":
            self.slide.placeholders[2].insert_picture(data[2])

slides = [
    ["USA Weather",       #data[0]
     "Subtitle(Bullet)",
     "girl.png",
     3],
    ["Malaysia Weather",       #data[0]
     "Content(Bullet)",
     "",
     3],
    ["China Weather",       #data[0]
     "This is a brown Fox",
     "",
     3]
]

for es in slides:
    Myslide(es)

prs.save('test.pptx')
os.startfile("test.pptx")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, it's `add_picture` …

For example:

```py
bottomLeftPicture = slide.shapes.add_picture(
    bottomLeftGraphicFilename,
    bottomLeftPicX,
    bottomLeftPicY,
    bottomLeftPicWidth,
    bottomLeftPicHeight,
)
```

Comment: Will you please give me whole code, because I don't know where to insert your code.

Comment: You insert it after you create a slide. In this case the slide is in a variable called `slide`.

Comment: Please update your answer with full code. (Because I am getting so many errors)